# Discord.js: Cannot read property 'setActivity' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm wondering why `setActivity` seems to go undefined. I've set up an Event Handler which works perfectly fine for my 'message' and 'ready' event. But as soon as I added this line of code to my 'ready' event to give my bot a custom status it for some reason does not work and I am unsure why. Since I don't know if it's to do with my Event Handler or 'ready' event I will show both files below. :)

Event Handler:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
    const load_dir = (dirs) => {
        const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./Natsuki Events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for (const file of eventFiles) {
            const event = require(`../Natsuki Events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            const eventName = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, Discord, client))
        }
    }

    ['Client', 'Guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

'ready' event:

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
    console.log('Natsuki is online!');
    client.user.setActivity("A game with That Penguin Guy || Type 'n! help'");
}
```

Comment: The error message isn't saying that setActivity is  undefined, but it's one step before that - client.user is undefined.

Comment: Do you know how I can make them defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the activity of your bot in its constructor, not in the ready event to make sure that the bot can go online with the correct information and to avoid issues with other timings.

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
  /* Your other options like intents */
  presence: {
    activities: [{
      type: 0,
      name: "A game with That Penguin Guy || Type 'n! help'"
    }],
  },
});
```

Relevant Discord.JS docs:

- [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) (the constructor is listed at the top with parameters)
- [ClientOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions) (presence is the 4th from the bottom)
- [PresenceData](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceData)
- [ActivitiesOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivitiesOptions)

Relevant Discord docs:

- [Activity Object](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#activity-object)

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking, but I'm still an amateur when it comes to coding, especially discord.js. I plan starting an online JavaScript course some time soon. I would like to know where exactly to include this coding. I have tried multiple locations and all seem to give the same result of `.Playing` being undefined. I do plan on getting better at coding, sorry if this was meant to be obvious for me!

Comment: Whooops! That was my bad, sorry. I didn't test the code before posting and made a wrong guess based on the docs. ActivityType is an enum that you can only use with TypeScript. You should get away with setting the type to 0, I updated the answer to reflect that :) And don't worry about asking! We all started small :)